# Is there a term for "adverb verb"s and/or "redundant adverb verb"s?

Tags: verbs, synonyms, terminology, adverbs

This is a meta question of this one: [How can I omit adverbs to impart a strong feeling?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329296/how-can-i-omit-adverbs-to-impart-a-strong-feeling) Like the original question, I'm trying to find some tool/list/book that helps one convert "adverb verb"s into stronger "verb"s. For example:

| Adverb Verb | Verb |
| --- | --- |
| Gently brushed | massaged |
| Quietly said | whispered |
| Quickly ran | ran |

That last one is an example of a "redundant adverb verb," so it's reduced to merely its "verb." **I'm putting these terms in quotes because I'm making them up. Do they have official terminology?**

Comment: There isn't always a verb with the meaning you want; it's not a simple matter of combining things. There are, however, specialized verbs for doing things in special ways, especially important things like talking. Verbs like [_snap, cackle,_ and _pipe up](https://web.stanford.edu/~zwicky/in-a-manner-of-speaking.pdf)_, for instance. Many incorporate specific behaviors for which there is no adverb, so this isn't a matter of adverbs -- it's general vocabulary. Make friends with a thesaurus and the OED, is all I can tell you.

Comment: Stephen King has a term for extraneous adverbs in his book "On Writing", but I can't find my copy right now. It certainly isn't "official terminology", though.